using columns in Word makes page number disappear
I have a page in Word with a list of character traits, which I put into three columns so they should nicely fit on one page.
Then I noticed that the next page skipped a number! (the page with the columns is 237, and the next page is 239).
I've been trying to read up on section breaks, and I'm understanding that using columns is using section breaks, which is somehow "swallowing up" my page 238...
I've been spending hours and trying to fix it but nothing helps...
Fascinatingly, when I save my word document as a pdf, the missing page is there as a blank page!
Edited to add: Another interesting fact: When I copied pages 235 through 239 and pasted them into a new document, the numbering was normal 1 through 4...


indeed strange you don't see page 238 in your document. Great you've tried it in pdf and realized the empty page! That generally happens when you've some non visible characters (sometimes only line break(s)) sitting on a page. First I'd restart Word (maybe even the complete pc and try whether the empty page would appear afterwards)

Tried restarting both. Didn't help unfortunately.

This is difficult to diagnose without the actual problem document. Try saving a copy of your document to OneDrive or DropBox. Pare that copy to start at the page before your columns and going to two pages following your columns. Post a link here so we can see it. My guess is the header/footer setting of Different First Page in the page without a number showing. Here is my writing on Page Numbers in Word: https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#PageNumbers

It's hard to say for sure without seeing the document itself, but one possibility is that the break after the word zealous at the bottom of page 237 is a 'Section Page (Odd Page)' break, which would cause a blank page to be inserted between pages 237 and 239 in a PDF, but no blank even page would be shown in Word.
Try replacing that break with a 'Section Break (Next Page)' break. For example, double-click the double dotted line that indicates the break to open the Page Setup dialog box. On the Layout tab, make sure that the Apply to field at the bottom is set to This section, and then, at teh top, if the Section start field is set to Odd page, select New page instead.

The "Section Field" was set to Continous, but I changed it to New Page to see what would happen, and the entire list jumped onto pg 238, leaving 237 blank. The only thing on 237 now is a section break which has "Section Start" at Odd page...

I just edited my original post to add that interestingly enough, when I copy and paste the pages into a new document, the numbering is fine...
